# finding all primes $p$ for which a given number is a quadratic residue

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity, quadratic-residues

I have seen an exercise on the Apostol, but I haven't understood some passages. I would be very grateful if you could solve my doubts.

The problem is

> **Find all primes $p$ for which 3 is a Quadratic Residue**

The problem is modelled by $\left(3\mid p\right)=1$; apply Law of quadratic reciprocity and obtain

$$\left(3\mid p\right)=\left(p\mid 3\right)=(-1)^{\left(p-1 \right)\left(3-1 \right)/4}$$

Observes that the value of $\left(3\mid p\right)$ depends from $p\mod 3$ and from the sign of the exponent, or $p\mod4$. Hence, $p\mod12$ is considered. Finally, the author observes that since $\phi\left(12\right)=4$, there are only four cases to consider.

And, up to this point, everything is crystal clear.

The exercise then proceeds saying that the cases to analyse are:

- $p\equiv1\left(\mod12\right)$
- $p\equiv5\left(\mod12\right)$
- $p\equiv7\left(\mod12\right)$
- $p\equiv11\left(\mod12\right)$

I don't understand the logic behind selecting the numbers 1, 5, 7, and 11. Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Comment: indeed, we know if p is prime, it must meet these criterion e.g p will not be congruent to 4. Can you guess why 3 and 9 aren't there?

Comment: did you get it yet? Since we are working mod 12 if p=3,9 then we know that 12 = 4x3 and that p is some multiple of 3. Make sense? Just look at some trivial cases such as p=15 or p = 21. Typically we look at mod8 and mod4, and you should get use to using this tool. For example in mod2 we would need p = 1(mod2)

Comment: Also, great question...when I took number theory, there were a bunch of comp. sci. guys in the class, and they had already been very exposed to modular arithmetic, and I had the same problem. Well, now you know, and this well help you with many questions.

Answer (score 1):

If $p = 2, 3$, then $p$ is a multiple of $2$ or $3$.  Otherwise, it is not a multiple of $2$ or $3$, which implies $p \equiv 1,5, 7, 11$ modulo $12$.

This is because if a number is even, then it is even modulo an even number, and vice versa.  Same for multiples of $3$.

Answer (score 0):

See these 2 examples

1. To evaluate `(3 | 11)` the integers in Gauss's lemma are

   > 3,6,9,1,4

   and two of these are larger than 11/2, so

   > (3 | 11) = (-1)^2 = 1

   Also

   > 5^2 ≡ 3 mod 11

   so 3 is a square mod 11, as expected.

   1. To evaluate `(3 | 19)` the integers in Gauss's lemma are

   > 3,6,9,12,15,18,2,5,8

   and three of these are larger than 19/2, so

   > (3 | 19) = (-1)^3 = -1

   And that's why it has no solutions.

This shows 3 is a quadratic residue of 11 but not 19